# Can't display blob image with base64_encode

Tags: php, mysql, blob

I'm having problem with displaying image which is stored in a database as a blob. In localhost it works perfect, but on the server it doesn't show anything. Could someone help me please. I've already surfed the internet to find the answer, and read many forums but still couldn't find the answer.

Here is my code.

```
<form action="index.php" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                  File:
                  <input type="file" name="image"> <input type="submit" value="upload">
                </form>

                <?php 
                $file = $_FILES['image']['tmp_name'];

                if(!isset($file))
                  echo "Please select some image";

                else 
                {
                  $tmpImageName=$_FILES['image']['tmp_name'];
                  $image_name = addslashes($_FILES['image']['name']);
                  $image_size = getimagesize($_FILES['image']['tmp_name']);
                  $handle      = fopen( $tmpImageName, 'r' );
                  $content = fread( $handle, filesize( $tmpImageName ) );
                  fclose($handle);

                  if($image_size==FALSE)
                    echo "That's not an image";

                  else 
                  {

                    $sql="insert into image values ('','$image_name','".mysql_real_escape_string($content)."')";

                    mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());


                    $res = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM image "); 
                    while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($res)) 
                    {
                      echo "<img src=data:image/jpeg;base64," . (base64_encode(($row['Image']))) . " width=60px height=60px>";
                    }
                  }

                }

                ?>
```

Comment: What PHP error do you get? You should enable error reporting. Also check if you receive the right base64. Also you have a real issue regarding content validation and SQL security (injection, etc.)

Comment: This is why people moved to prepared mysql engines with prepared statements support (mysqli/pdo)

Comment: @AlexvandenHoogen there is no error, i checked base64, everything is correct, code starts with PNG word

Comment: @Peter do you know any tutorial on inserting image with PDO. By the way, which one is better PDO or MySqli

Comment: PDO is better than MySQLi. Regarding your base64, I mean is the base64 printed correctly when you echo it in PHP? Is your html source ok? What happens if you copy/paste the URL of the `img src` in your browser? Do you get the image?

Comment: Both are ok, PDO is richer, mysqli is simple and more similiar to old `mysql_*` functions. There is nice example how to read/write image from database in php manual http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.lobs.php

Comment: @AlexvandenHoogen base64 is printed correctly, and I don't get the image from the url of image, still the broken image's icon

Comment: @AlexvandenHoogen if I insert image directly into database by phpmyadmin manually, and try to show it, I get image

Comment: Ah, so encoding is not the problem than.. It is the decoding. That is because you do `mysql_real_escape_string` on the image and not `base64_decode` to store it in the database. Although I'm not sure if you have to do `mysql_real_escape_string` after the `base64_decode`.

Answer (score 1):

try

```
 echo '<img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,'.base64_encode($row['image']) .' "/>';
```